# Is there any ways to call non-static method within static method

Tags: php

I would like to call non-static method within static method. for example

Instead of calling method the following

```
$user = new User();
$userdata = $user->data($argument);
```

I would like to call as the following

```
$usedata = User::data($argument);
```

Firstly I build with the following setting

```
Class User{

    public static function __callStatic($methodname, $argument) {
    $objName =   __CLASS__; 
    $obj = new $objName;
    return $obj->find($argument);
    }
    public function find($argument) {
        return $argument*2;
    } 
}

 echo User::find(2);
```

But It show Warning message but code is successfully executed. Is there any other better solution for this scenario ? Sorry for any grammar mistake that I made since I am not native speaker and I am not very fluent with english.

Comment: Static methods have no context; no instance variables to work with, so it makes no sense to call a non-static method within a static method. What would the non-static method's context be? If it has no context, make it static itself. If it does have context, then so does your static method in which case you should make your static method non-static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your find() method don't use the class context ($this), and that you need to call this method statically, then just declare it as static.